# User access to SQL Server Agent - job activity monitor

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to check some job that ran on a SQL Server 2008, but the user used when logging on to that server can not have sysadmin rights.

So my question is can I have an user that can access SQL Server Agent - Job Activity Monitor, but that user is not in the sysadmin group?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2008 R2? It doesn't matter with this specific question but it's important to be explicit and consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the user to `msdb` and put them in the `SQLAgentOperatorRole` fixed database role. For more information see the Books Online topic [How to: Configure a User to Create and Manage SQL Server Agent Jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187901%28sql.100%29.aspx).

In T-SQL, this would be:

```
USE msdb;
GO
CREATE USER UserName FROM LOGIN [UserName];
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'SQLAgentOperatorRole', N'UserName';
GO
```

In SQL Server 2012 that `sp_addrolemember` should not be used; instead:

```
ALTER ROLE [SQLAgentOperatorRole] ADD MEMBER [UserName];
```